# iOS: Duplicate interface definition for class 'EAGLView'

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, metaio

I am developing an iOS project where i'm using Cocos2d,3d and also Augmented reality based Metaio SDK [Metaio SDK link](http://www.metaio.com/sdk/) in an iOS project.
This Metaio integration uses a file EAGLView.mm and EAGLView.h. Cocos2d is already having EAGLView.m and EAGLView.h. If i build, i get

```
`Duplicate interface definition for class 'EAGLView'`
```

How can i make both files working in this project? Please advise!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refractor one of the class names. I think the would be the quickest, easiest way. Xcode has an option similar to ^click>refractor and choose name.
I also recommend saying yes, when Xcode asks you if you want to take a snapshot of the project first, just in case.

Comment: go to the .h file, right click or ctrl click on the name of the class, choose refractor, choose name. one fair warning though, if I were you, i would remove one of them(either the mateo or the other one), refractor the other one in the project, and put it in again, because i have a feeling refractoring works with a regular expression and would refractor both of the classes. also, you will have to change the file name yourself

Comment: I didn't get you. I can't remove either of the files, because both does different purposes. I tried refactoring Metaio's EAGLView.h, but it throws error as "Can’t refactor code used in this language.EAGLView.h is imported or included by files that are Objective-C++, not Objective-C or C: ARELViewController.mm, EAGLView.mm, and 1 others."

Comment: Oh, yeah, I didn't notice it was an Objective-C++ library. What I meant be removing one of them, is removing it temporarily from the project, until you finish refractoring the other. In any case, if Xcode can't do it automatically, you can maybe write your own RegEx and do a find-replace on the files and change the name of the class.